# Formatting Excel Laravel with array data

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, laravel-excel

I'm trying to write an excel from a laravel controller where i have all the data in an array, and i managed to write it, but i have to format it now, this is the array that i have:

```
[2020-12-30 13:22:05] local.DEBUG: array (
  0 => 
  array (
    0 => '1',
    1 => '2',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    0 => 'Test Name 1',
    1 => 'Test Name 2',
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    0 => 'user',
    1 => 'user2',
  ),
  3 => 
  array (
    0 => '1',
    1 => '2',
  ),
)
```

This is the way i'm creating the Excel:

```
Excel::create('Filename', function($excel) use ($budgets) {

            $excel->sheet('Sheetname', function($sheet) use ($budgets) { //$budgets is the array i'm printing on Log

                $sheet->fromArray($budgets);

            });

        })->export('xls');
```

And this is the way that my excel is printing it:

|  |  |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |
| Test Name 1 | Test Name 2 |
| user1 | user2 |
| 1 | 2 |

And the way i want to print it is:

| Code | Name | User | Number |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Test Name 1 | user1 | 1 |
| 2 | Test Name 2 | user2 | 2 |

But i don't know how to achieve this. Can anyone help me with this?

//edits//

```
I added some code to re estructure the array, now i have this:

$users = ['Code', 'Name', 'User', 'Number'];
        for ($i=0; $i<count($code); $i++){
            array_push($users, array($code[$i], $name[$i], $user[$i], $number[$i]));
        }
        
        Log::debug($users);
```

And this is the Log:

```
[2020-12-30 15:17:40] local.DEBUG: array (
  0 => 'Code',
  1 => 'Name',
  2 => 'User',
  3 => 'Number',
  4 => 
  array (
    0 => '1',
    1 => 'Test Name 1',
    2 => 'user1',
    3 => '1',
  ),
  5 => 
  array (
    0 => '2',
    1 => 'Test Name 2',
    2 => 'user2',
    3 => '2',
  ),
)
```

But i'm getting this error:

```
[message] => Row `Code` must be array.
            [class] => PHPExcel_Exception
```

Answer (score 1):

You will could re-structure your array.
To get the print you want array should look like:

```
$budget = [
    ['Code', 'Name', 'User', 'Number'],
    [1, 'Test Name 1', 'user1', 1],
    ...
];
```

Comment: I'm trying to do this now:
$budgets = array('Code', 'Name', 'User', 'Number');
        for ($i=0; $i<count($code); $i++){
            array_push($users, array($code[$i], $name[$i], $user[$i], $number[$i]));
        }
but i'm getting an error "Row `Code` must be array."

Comment: Is you variable $code instance of an array? Also you named "header" array $budgets, but in for loop you are pushing into $users.

Comment: Sorry, yes, i made a mistake with the array names, it's the same users array that i'm declaring with the "headers". I'm going to edit the post, so you can see it more clearly

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so, i managed to re-structure the array and getting the Excel the way i wanted doing this:

```
public function generateExcel(Request $request)
    {
        $code = $request->input('code');
        $name = $request->input('name');
        $user = $request->input('user');
        $number = $request->input('number');

        $users = array();
        array_push($users, array('Code', 'Name', 'User', 'Number'));
        for ($i=0; $i<count($code); $i++){
            array_push($users, array($code[$i], $name[$i], $user[$i], $number[$i]));
        }
        
        
        Excel::create('Filename', function($excel) use ($users) {

            $excel->sheet('Sheetname', function($sheet) use ($users) {

                $sheet->fromArray($users);

            });

        })->export('xls');
        return true;
```